# Equilibrium probability in a markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

can someone please tell me what an equilibrium probability in a markov chain is and what the relation between the equlibrium probability and equilibrium distribution is?

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to elaborate on what "equilibrium probability" is supposed to mean...

Comment: Yes this was what I asked for! I thought that someone would know what it is because I could not find a definition of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you are referring to what is more commonly known as a stationary distribution. Suppose you had a Markov chain $X_t$ for $t>0$. After it runs for a long time, you could take a look at its state, e.g. $X_{1000}$. What would that state be? Well, we don't know for sure, but there's a chance it's equal to $A$, another chance it's $B$, etc., i.e. it follows some random distribution probability. This is the stationary distribution, and is a vector of probabilities that sum to 1.

The point of a stationary distribution is that it's a limiting distribution; as $t$ tends to infinity, the distribution of states you might find yourself in (without knowing the immediate prior state) tends to some limit.

However, there is a caveat: the stationary distribution doesn't always exist.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation, it was helpful! But I was looking for a general definition or explanation of "equilibrium probability" because in my paper they define a probability and call it "equilibrium probability" and I have never heard of it and can´t find something useful in the internet...So I thought that might have some relation to the "equlibrium probability"

Comment: In the context of Markov chains, equilibrium probability most likely refers to the stationary distribution. However, since you have a paper that defines it, it would help a lot if you could provide that definition, to be sure.

Comment: The paper is about clonal populations and their growth in fluctuating environments...etc. The equilibrium probability is defined as $p_i = \sum_{j}{p_j b_{i j}} $ it describes the average duration of an environment i, where $b_{i j}$ is the transition probability=environment change probability...

Comment: Then it is indeed the stationary distribution; the expression you gave is the formula for the balance equations $\pi=\pi P$, where $\pi$ is the stationary distribution (a row vector) and $P$ is the transition matrix. Basically, equilibrium probability and stationary distribution are the same thing. Your paper probably prefers to use the term 'equilibrium' because it carries a notion of stability with it.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much :-)